# Occasionally my home directory gets 0777 permissions. How does that happen?

Tags: centos, permissions

Several times a year, I find I that my home directory magically got permissions 0777 (the symptom being ssh not longer trusting my keys in `.ssh/*`).
I have no idea how this happens. I `chmod 755 $HOME` and it works for a month or two (sorry, no better statistics).

The machine is a CentOS 7 that is kept up-to-date, I am the admin. The box is not exposed to the Internet (in a 10.0.0.0/8 net), other than through a web proxy. I have no reports about the same effect from the other 10 users on this system.

The HW is a Samsung NVME. `mount` says this about it:

```
 /dev/nvme0n1p3 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

My first suspicion was a monthly cron job. But my cron tab is empty.
Root's crontab looks innocent:

```
# crontab -l
30 15 * * * /usr/bin/find / /home /opt -xdev > /var/run/files
```

The system's `/etc/cron.d` files also look harmless (I never touched anything after system installation, so they are pristine):

```
# cat /etc/cron.d/0hourly /etc/cron.d/raid-check /etc/cron.d/sysstat
# Run the hourly jobs
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
# Run system wide raid-check once a week on Sunday at 1am by default
0 1 * * Sun root /usr/sbin/raid-check

# Run system activity accounting tool every 10 minutes
*/10 * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1
# 0 * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 600 6 &
# Generate a daily summary of process accounting at 23:53
53 23 * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 -A
```

Any ideas where I can look or what's going on?

Comment: Can you use `inotifywait` to watch for a change. It won't tell you what, bit will tell you when. You should only watch on the event that you want (I think attrib).

Comment: `ls -ld $HOME` should tell you when it was last changed, that might narrow down culprits.

Comment: Root shouldn’t have a crontab entry at all, so that’s pretty suspicious. I’d look to see the time stamp on the spool file and see who was logged in at the same time